# How to apply filter at search of woocommerce products?

Tags: filters, search, plugins

I want to change woocommerce search. And want to limit the search to Product title and Category and Tag only excluding description and short description.

Search Form is in plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce-template.php file, Named `get_product_search_form()`. but how to apply filter at search of this form.

Answer (score 2):

There are no specific searches for WooCommerce.  It utilizes WordPress default search system.  By default WordPress does not search within tags ( not sure if that has changed for WP 3.6 ).  It searches only in titles and description.  This is the same if it is for a product.

Answer (score 1):

Here I am, a little late, but this Question came up in my search, and I thought I could drop two links about it.

A plugin that could prove useful is [SearchWP](https://searchwp.com/). But, if you would like to read a bit and write your own code, you could take a look at [James Collings' blog](http://jamescollings.co.uk/blog/extending-woocommerce-search-query-include-custom-fields/), which contains a lot of useful information and hints.

**Note:** When reading Collings' article and copy/pasting his code into your own, don't forget to change the names of WP tables to a more portable format; for example:

```
wp_postmeta
```

should become

```
" . $wpdb->prefix . "postmeta
```

And, of course, put a

```
global $wpdb;
```

line at the beginning of the functions using the prefixes (otherwise PHP won't know where to go to load that `$wpdb` object)